# python program to grep the output of a file with a time range

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2.6.6

I have a sample file 1.csv

1.csv

```
11887788201606180000 value=1 sat sun mon tue , 998848494 992920209 992828282 kdkkdkdf 992828228 o333448482 

28283838201606180000 value-2 jan feb mar apr , 8849494994 49499494 499494949 49949494  499494484 449494994

33838383201606180000 value-2 jan feb mar apr , 8849494994 49499494 499494949 49949494  499494484 449494994

47474747201606190000 value-2 jan feb mar apr , 8849494994 49499494 499494949 49949494  499494484 449494994

47474747201606200000 value-2 jan feb mar apr , 8849494994 49499494 499494949 49949494  499494484 449494994
```

I want to get the data from time range 20160618 to 20160619

and my expected output should like this:

```
11887788201606180000 value=1 sat sun mon tue , 998848494 992920209 992828282 kdkkdkdf 992828228 o333448482 

28283838201606180000 value-2 jan feb mar apr , 8849494994 49499494 499494949 49949494  499494484 449494994

33838383201606180000 value-2 jan feb mar apr , 8849494994 49499494 499494949 49949494  499494484 449494994

47474747201606190000 value-2 jan feb mar apr , 8849494994 49499494 499494949 49949494  499494484 449494994
```

The code i have written is

```
import csv
import sys
import time
import datetime
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from_raw = raw_input('\nEnter From date :')
    from_date = datetime
    print 'From date: = ' + str(from_date)
    to_raw = raw_input('\nEnter TO Date  :')
    to_date = datetime
    in_file = './file.csv'
    for line in in_file:
        fields = line.split(',')
        found_date = datetime.date
        if from_date <= found_date <= to_date:
            print line
    in_file.close()
```

I am executing it like

python script.py 1.csv

I am able to key  in the start date and end date with the script but not able to get the expected output

please help

Answer (score 0):

Just reading your code the problem is in the line

```
fields = line.split(',')
```

You are splitting the line at the "," which is not what you want. Given that the date substring is consistently in the same place in the string I would try an easy solution which is

```
found_date = line[8:16]
```

And also remove the following line:

```
found_date = datetime.date
```

This line will change the found_date in the line to the current date/time which you do no want to happen.

These simple changes should solve your coding issue as long as the input format is consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that didnt solve the problem